# MVAPICH deadlocks on CUDA memory while kernel is running

Tags: c++, cuda, mpi, mpich

I try to get a MPI-CUDA program working with MVAPICH CUDA8. I did run the program successfully with openMPI before but I want to test if I get better performance with MVAPICH. Unfortunately the program gets stuck in MPI_Isend if a CUDA kernel is running at the same time when using MVAPICH.

I downloaded MVAPICH2-2.2 and built it from the source with the configuration flags

--enable-cuda --disable-mcast

to enable MPI calls on cuda memory. mcast was disabled because I could not compile it without the flag.

I used the following flags before running the application:

```
export MV2_USE_CUDA=1
export MV2_GPUDIRECT_GDRCOPY_LIB=/path/to/gdrcopy/
export MV2_USE_GPUDIRECT=1
```

MPI_Isend/recv work fine when at the same time no CUDA kernel is running. But in my program it is important that MPI sends and receives data from and to GPU memory, while a kernel is running.

I came up with two possible reasons for that behavior. First, MVAPICH tries to run his own CUDA kernel for some reason to send data from GPU memory and this kernel does not get scheduled because the GPU is already fully utilized. Second possibility: MVAPICH uses cudaMemcpy somewhere (not the async version), which blocks until the kernel finishes execution.

Could someone confirm one of my assumptions? And is there a flag in MVAPICH that solves this problem that I am not aware of?

**EDIT:**

Here a "simpel" code that illustrates my problem. When executing the code with openMPI, it executes and terminates correctly. With mvapich2 it deadlocks at the marked MPI_Send function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <mpi.h>


__global__ void kernel(double * buffer, int rank)
{
    volatile double *buf = buffer;
    if(rank == 0){
        while(buf[0] != 3){}
    } else {
        while(buf[0] != 2){}
    }
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    double host_buffer[1];
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int world_size, world_rank;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    printf("Im rank %d\n", world_rank);
    cudaSetDevice(world_rank);

    double * dev_buffer;
    cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc(&dev_buffer, sizeof(double));
    if(world_rank == 0){
        host_buffer[0] = 1;
        cudaError_t err = cudaMemcpy(dev_buffer, host_buffer, sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        MPI_Send(dev_buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("[%d]First send does not deadlock\n", world_rank);
    }else {
        MPI_Recv(dev_buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("[%d]Received first message\n", world_rank);
    }

    cudaStream_t stream, kernel_stream;
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);
    cudaStreamCreate(&kernel_stream);

    printf("[%d]launching kernel\n", world_rank);
    kernel<<<208, 128, 0, kernel_stream>>>(dev_buffer, world_rank);

    if(world_rank == 0){
        //rank 0
        host_buffer[0] = 2;
        cudaMemcpyAsync(
            dev_buffer, host_buffer, sizeof(double),
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,
            stream
        );
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);

        printf("[%d]Send message\n", world_rank);
        MPI_Send(dev_buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); //mvapich2 deadlocks here
        printf("[%d]Message sent\n", world_rank);

        printf("[%d]Receive message\n", world_rank);
        MPI_Recv(dev_buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("[%d]Message received\n", world_rank);

        cudaStreamSynchronize(kernel_stream);
        printf("[%d]kernel finished\n", world_rank);

    } else {
        //rank 1
        printf("[%d]Receive message\n", world_rank);
        MPI_Recv(dev_buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        printf("[%d]Message received\n", world_rank);

        cudaStreamSynchronize(kernel_stream);
        printf("[%d]kernel finished\n", world_rank);

        host_buffer[0] = 3;
        cudaMemcpyAsync(
            dev_buffer, host_buffer, sizeof(double),
            cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,
            stream
        );
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream);

        printf("[%d]Send message\n", world_rank);
        MPI_Send(dev_buffer, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("[%d]Message sent\n", world_rank);

    }
    printf("[%d]Stopped execution\n", world_rank);
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: A small reproducer would improve this question :)

Comment: added a simple code example that illustrates my problem.

Comment: This looks like it shouldn't ever work. The fact that is did work with OpenMPI was probably more of an accident than anything else.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the code should not work? And sorry for the not so clean code. It was the shortes example I came up with that showed the problem.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming that MPI_Send can overlap successfully with a running kernel, and that the kernel will maintain memory coherence at the same time. But there are many reasons why that might not be the case. I am not sure that it is guaranteed that a device to device copy can overlap with a running kernel, and particularly a kernel which has grid dimensions intended to fully occupy the devices in question. In general, the whole idea of a "resident kernel" is (IMHO) a broken one. The kernel launch latency on linux is less than 10us. If that is critical, MPI+GPus is the wrong solution

Comment: My goal is not to overcome kernel launch latency. My goal is to overlap inter-node communication with computation. I am also aware of memory coherency issues. But lets but the reasons aside on why to do this. If I understand you correctly the reason why it should not work is because GPUDirect cannot copy data from GPU to the network adapter while the GPU is fully occupied by a cuda kernel? I would argue that this is not true, as I managed to do so using openMPI as well as using InfiniBand verbs directly for communication.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the OpenMPI implementation didn't use a combination of D2H and H2D pathways to effect transfers? Because those will probably work. But a D2D transfer effectively runs a kernel, and that might not. My point is that you are making assumptions about the internal implementation of two different MPI codebases which are basically undocumented, and you can't sanely assume something like this would work

Comment: @talonmies I agree on the point that I made assumptions about the MPI implementations that might be false. But I don't see why a memory transfer from GPU memory to the network adapter and back using GPUDirect RDMA should run a kernel. It is certainly possible that the problem is caused by mvapich trying to run a kernel like you said. But I don't think that it is not possible in general. I'm pretty certain that openMPI uses GPUDirect RDMA and no D2H copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got back to this problem and used gdb to debug the code.

Apparently, the problem is the eager protocol of MVAPICH2 implemented in src/mpid/ch3/channels/mrail/src/gen2/ibv_send.c. The eager protocol uses a cuda_memcpy without async, which blocks until the kernel execution finishes.

The program posted in the question runs fine by passing MV2_IBA_EAGER_THRESHOLD 1 to mpirun. This prevents MPI to use the eager protocol and uses the rendez-vous protocol instead.

Patching the MVAPICH2 source code does solve the problem as well. I changed the synchronous cudaMemcpys to cudaMemcpyAsync in the files

- src/mpid/ch3/channels/mrail/src/gen2/ibv_send.c
- src/mpid/ch3/channels/mrail/src/gen2/ibv_recv.c
- src/mpid/ch3/src/ch3u_request.c

The change in the third file is only needed for MPI_Isend/MPI_Irecv. Other MPI functions might need some additional code changes.